# Getting the first and the last digit and do a formula in python

Tags: python, integer

I used this method

```
for n in range(10,99):

  def firstDigit(n) :
 
     while n >= 10:
         n = n / 10;
     

     return int(n)
 

  def lastDigit(n) :
 
    
     return (n % 10)
     
 z = firstDigit(n)**2 + lastDigit(n)**2 + firstDigit(n) + lastDigit(n);

 if z == n:

  print(z)
```

But gave this error why?

IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: why would you put the function definitions **inside** the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Paku.

By the error, i can only infer that there is a problem at the indentation. Are you sure your function looks exacly like this?

```
for n in range(10,99):

    def firstDigit(n):
 
         while n >= 10:
             n = n / 10;
    
         return int(n)

def lastDigit(n):
    return (n % 10)
     
z = firstDigit(n)**2 + lastDigit(n)**2 + firstDigit(n) + lastDigit(n);

if z == n:
    print(z)
```

Comment: yeah Im 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

You have to indent every time you use a loop , function or decision statement: `for`, `while`,`def` or `if`.
Python is VERY sensitive about indenting.
Here, you have to indent your variable z  with the same vertical line of `def`.
So, your code needs to be like this

```
for n in range(10,99):

  def firstDigit(n) :
 
     while n >= 10:
         n = n / 10;
     

     return int(n)
 

  def lastDigit(n) :
 
    
     return (n % 10)
     
  z = firstDigit(n)**2 + lastDigit(n)**2 + firstDigit(n) + lastDigit(n);

  if z == n:

     print(z)
```